# Function default value not working normally in react native

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So, I have this asynchronous function

```
 loadData = async (value=1) => {
        await this.loadSalesData(value);
```

it works fine when I pass a value to it, however when it is called from the navigation events

```
<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={this.loadData} />
```

it does not work, so I did a print statement on

```
 loadData = async (value=1) => {
        print(value) // value  Object { "action": Object {"key": "Overview",  "type": 
                     //"Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION", ......
        await this.loadSalesData(value);
```

any idea how I can use default object in this case?
I even tried to do something like we used to in ES5 using a turnery operator but it's still the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the arguments from `onDidFocus` callback and just want to use `loadData` default value, you could try something like

```
<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => this.loadData()} />
```